# How can we tell if a Bayes Rule is unique?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

There is a theorem within Bayesian statistics that if a Bayes rule is unique, then it is admissible (in that no other rule dominates it under mean squared error). I was wondering how one might be able to go about confirming if a Bayes rule is indeed unique. Would anyone have any idea? Thanks!